# Creating a plain html home page AMP with WordPress running the other pages

Tags: html, css, wordpress, amp-html

Gday

I like to know how you would go about creating a home page in plain html and have WordPress run the other pages?

The reason is I’d like to create a solely plain html website but I need WordPress for my contact page it has a large form on it and I use a plugin to generate it and forms are a bit beyond my knowledge at the moment to create a contact page myself.

(I have tried creating a template page but then WordPress adds unnecessary code [from plugins ] and makes the AMP invalid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I'd try and keep it self contained in WordPress itself.

If for some reason you really want a separate HTML/PHP Homepage, follow these steps:

1. Add a `my-homepage.php` file to your `/wp-content/themes/ACTIVE-THEME` directory
2. Inside that file put the following code:
3. Add a new page  (Pages > Add New)
4. Give it a recognizable name like "My Homepage"
5. In the "Template" selector on the right hand side, pick "My HTML Homepage" and click Publish
6. Go to Settings > Reading, change **Your homepage displays** to **A static page** and pick the page you just made

Now you can add your own code as you see fit. Nothing "WordPress" related will get loaded or hooked in since there's no functions on that file - so you're free to code HTML (or PHP) to your heart's content.

You can see a bit more indepth answer over on WPSE: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/296592/how-to-use-custom-html-file-instead-of-wordpress-homepage

Comment: Thanks I did try that but then WordPress adds unnecessary code and makes the AMP invalid

Comment: Depending on the plugins you may need to use `remove_action` to remove it if they're forcing their way in. Unfortunately, since that may be a bit over your skillset right now. I've added a different method. I'm not a huge fan of it, but without moving your WP to a subdirectory, something like that may be your best bet.

Comment: I there a reason why you don’t recommend it?

Comment: Because you're technically editing a core file. It's a *very very* basic and easily reversible edit. But it may get overwritten in WordPress Core version updates, so may need to be reapplied when WordPress is updated), as well as it may get confusing for anybody who takes over the site later (or your distant future self!).